# Is this the correct way to solve the question below

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Five character security codes for a store,are created by using a letter followed by 4 non-repeating numerical digits or using a digit followed by 4 non-repeating letters. 
The total number of security codes possible is?

My work:

Hqrscter security codes-a,b,c,d= 4 non repeating letters
And 1,2,3,4= 4 non repeating digits 
There are 33463 number of security codes possible 
Is this the correct answer ? If not how do I solve this question,please help

Answer (score 1):

For the first one which begins with  a letter something I learned which is helpful but not always applicable is to draw boxes or lines to fill in representing how many choices you have at each stage : _ _ _ _ _  so  if we want to fill in the first box we decide how many choices we have. If using English alphabet we would have 26 letter choices so we'd start with $\underline{26} $ _ _ _ _ then figure out our next decision which is a number so we would have 10 choices in base 10 so now we have made it to $ \underline{26} \ \underline{10}$ _ _ _ . Since we cannot repeat we would have 9 digits to choose from next $ \underline{26} \ \underline{10} \ \underline{9}$ _ _ again our next decision we cannot repeat so only 8 choices again similarly for the last step we only have 7 choices so the final answer in this examples would be $$26 \cdot 10 \cdot 9 \cdot 8 \cdot 7 $$ 
A similar approach would work for the second option you have to solve for.

Comment: So is the answer 189,540 security codes possible ?

Comment: for the first part yes the second one you should be able to apply the same technique

Comment: So for the second step can I do 25*10**8*8*8

Comment: So what would be the final answer to the question?

Comment: second one is 10*26*25*24*23

Comment: So is the answer 680,069,520,000 because that doesn’t seem right to me

Comment: why doesn't it seem right?

Comment: if you go to a programming side of stack exchange maybe someone could show you what this code outputs so you can see that indeed there are many possible code combinations

Comment: Yes but the question is asking for the total number possible security codes

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand what your'e asking? If you are asking if that is the correct answer I do not know because I am only going off of what information you provided. It is up to you to decide if the steps make sense

Comment: The information I provided is the information I got to answer this question ,I’m actually in grade 12 and for one of the assignments my math teacher gave me this exact question that I posted above and I tried it but I’m not sure what the answer is

Comment: I understand you that you have provided me with the information which you were given and I answered the question accordingly

Comment: So the first and second step u did,do I need to multiply both the steps to get my final answer for the total number of security codes possible?

Comment: No you would add them

Comment: So basically for the first step u said to multiply 26•10•9•8•7 which is 189,540 and for the second step u said to multiply  10•26•25•24•23 which is 3,588,000 so then do I add the 2 to get my final answer?

Comment: yes that is what you do

Comment: So I add 189,540 which I multiplied in the first step and add it with the second step I multiplied and got 3,588,00 with

Comment: So is the answer 3,777,540 after adding the two?